# Where is the mistake for this query logic?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on some project and I have 8 tables I created tasks for my self for improving my knowledge and when I'm doing that I had a Problem during query
In below there is sample tables and data

```
CREATE TABLE Clients 
(ID NUMBER(10),
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Cbudget NUMBER(10,2),
CompanyID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID));
Describe Clients

CREATE TABLE Contracts 
(ID NUMBER(20),
ContractValue CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CompanyID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
ClientID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
TransactionID NUMBER(10) NOt NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID));
Describe Contracts

ALTER TABLE Contracts ADD ClientID NUMBER


CREATE TABLE "Transaction" 
(ID NUMBER(10), 
Type NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
Price NUMBER(10,2),
TDATE date,
ClientID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID));
Describe "Transaction"
```

here is the data

```
INSERT INTO Clients(ID,name,surname,Cbudget,CompanyID) VALUES (1,'hamza','bacara',98372.200,2);
INSERT INTO Clients(ID,name,surname,Cbudget,CompanyID) VALUES (2,'','bacara',87432.400,1);
INSERT INTO Clients(ID,name,surname,Cbudget,CompanyID) VALUES (3,'batikan','falay',213132.00,2);

INSERT INTO "Transaction"(ID,Type,Price,TDATE,ClientID)VALUES(1,'1',5000,current_date,2);
INSERT INTO "Transaction"(ID,Type,Price,TDATE,ClientID)VALUES(2,'1',6000,'11/09/2006',1);
INSERT INTO "Transaction"(ID,Type,Price,TDATE,ClientID)VALUES(3,'2',9000,current_date,3);
INSERT INTO Contracts(ID,ContractValue,CompanyID,ClientID,TransactionID)VALUES(1,'1 Million $',1,2,1);
INSERT INTO Contracts(ID,ContractValue,CompanyID,ClientID,TransactionID)VALUES(2,'50 Million $',2,1,2);
INSERT INTO Contracts(ID,ContractValue,CompanyID,ClientID,TransactionID)VALUES(3,'100 Million $',2,2,3);
```

and here is the query (it works but every time it just shows the data with '100 million $'

```
SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE ClientID IN 
(SELECT T.ClientID FROM "Transaction" T 
INNER JOIN Contracts CT ON CT.TransactionID = CT.id WHERE CT.ContractValue = '1 Million $');
```

I have also constraints (I'm not sure it's important for you)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [behavior of inner join inside exists sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033995/behavior-of-inner-join-inside-exists-sql)

Comment: unfortunately, I did not understand that because it has other keywords that I don't know yet.

Comment: All those `varchar` and `char` columns should really be the standard `varchar2`. `varchar` is officially reserved for future use and `char` is [rather specialised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your query is giving the correct result as per your data. (Only one change in the query `...ON CT.TransactionID = CT.id WHERE...` should be `...ON CT.TransactionID = T.id WHERE...`)

In the `CONTRACTS` table, `CLIENTID` 2 is assigned to two contracts `ID = 1 and 3`. so the query is matching with two clients.

If you will update the `CONTRACTS` table as follows then it is giving the correct result.

```
UPDATE CONTRACTS 
SET CLIENTID = 3 
WHERE ID = 3
```

<kbd>[db fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=900e5140c04a7bdc6dbab6b708f62e35)</kbd>

Comment: yeah, I realized that later on but thank you so much ^-^